# Single word (preferably noun) to describe an indecisive person

Tags: single-word-requests

I am writing a software which provides user an ability to either mark "will do" or "consider doing". Right now I need a word to describe the latter. People who want to do something, still consider doing something or, in general, are on the fence of doing something.

Comment: How about **undecided**?

Comment: @WeatherVane thanks for suggestion, however I hope for a noun though so as to have a multiple form later on

Comment: The other option "will do" is not a noun. If you want one here I suggest **ditherer** but it might be hard to find one that is not perjorative.

Comment: "Wishy-washy" comes to mind, but it sounds like you need something more diplomatic. I agree with "undecided".

Comment: Do you mean _indecisive_? Every wise person considers an important decision for some period of time. _Undecided_ and _indecisive_ are far from exact synonyms.

Comment: Not single words, but neither are yours. Seems like you're looking for three possible answers: *Will do*, *Will consider doing*, *Not sure* or *May consider doing*. The third is your "on the fence".

Comment: @RichardKayser I get that they are different for people. However, as a developer, it is not exactly my interest whether person will consider, is not fully sure or he might, they are all the same for me. My use case has 3 possible variants: 100% will do, "any other percentage > 0", "no will not". I would create a word "considerer" for second case, but made up words are bad for readability

Comment: To start I do consider *undecided* to be a noun. For the purpose of categorizing your applicants by the choice sets they make you may take them as *Decided* and *Open*. This would be an abbreviation for open minded. No doubt additional data will help them along.

Comment: @Nobody Your comments clarify the question for me. It now seems that you are giving your users a choice as far as some question is concerned, e.g., "Do you want X?" In that case, the possible answers would seem to be YES (your 100%), NO (your 0%), and MAYBE or NOT SURE (your  > 0% but < 100%). You could use these as nouns, i.e., so and so could be "a YES", so and so could be "a NO", or so and so could be "a MAYBE".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say, for example, that you want to ask your users "Are you in interested in X?" In that case, you could give them YES, NO, and MAYBE as the three possible answers. You could then use these as nouns (M-W) to categorize each respondent as  "a YES", "a NO", or "a MAYBE". So your indecisive person would be "**a MAYBE**".

A few additional examples:

Question: "Rich, are you going to play golf with us on Thursday?" Answer: "Put me down as **a maybe**."

Question: "Is Rich playing with us on Thursday? Answer: "He's **a maybe**."